# How to Upload APK to Google Compute Engine

Tags: apk, google-compute-engine

I have a server in Google Compute Engine, where i upload apk of my app manually so all the users get the latest update.
Is there any way that i can upload my apk via page of my website to the google compute engine server ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload file to your local drive on your compute engine instance, you need to create a way to do it on your backend. For example, if you have a PHP backend you can do it via a simple php script. Check this example for details: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
You can find similar simple solutions online for java or node.js backends as well.

Alternatively you can host the files on google cloud storage. For that you need to create a bucket and follow the steps here: https://cloud.google.fcom/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload .Then you can modify your website to have some webform + javascript code to do the upload.